# How to add an Ubuntu Launcher Icon to my PySide app?

Tags: python, qt, icons, pyqt, pyside

I've just written my very first little GUI-app using PySide. I just wanted to add an icon to it so it doesn't show up as a grey questionmark item in the Ubuntu Launcher. I would guess that something like that is a very simple thing to do, but I cannot find any information about it. Maybe I'm not searching correctly, or maybe I plain stupid, but I can't find out how to do that.

Does anybody have a tip or hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Unity, you would have to create a [desktop file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and store it in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`. The content of the file should look somehow like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AppName
Exec=/path/to/app
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I thought it was something I had to code using Qt, so indeed, I was way off! Thanks again!